# Error when installing Dynamics CRM Email Router - The Microsoft Exchange MAPI subsystem is not installed

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I am getting an error "Either there is no default email client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request" and "The Microsoft Exchange MAPI subsystem is not installed." I have installed the ExchangeMAPICdo and have also tried repairing the outlook installation after deleting the registry outlook key(based on a technet suggestion that the key may have been corrupted). I am unable to proceed with the installation. I am using Outlook 2013 Professional. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by deleting the registry entry for Outlook, installing the MAPI subsystem and CRM Email router in that order. Once the email router is installed, you may run Outlook repair to restore the deleted keys.